# Gate embedded as web service

Tags: java, service, web, gate

I will start developing `GATE` as web services based on my saved applications in Java.
Is it possible?
At the moment, my saved application includes `ANNIE Plugin`.

I researched on `GATE` and found that there was one plugin called "`NeOn`" and the web services for NeOn are not supported.

Should i write the GateListener as a Servlet?
I do not have any idea for how I can develop it in my program.
Can you help me please?

[Here](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-july09/slides-pdf/webservices.pdf) is an article that I have found that addresses my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tutorial with code available in module 8 in [the training material](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/TrainingCourseJune2013/). Take a look at the GateHandler class which:

- handles a request with a string parameter
- creates a GATE document
- puts it in a corpus
- processes it with a custom pipeline
- writes document features in the response

GATE embedded is easily integrated in a Spring application (the working example in module 8, running on a jetty server) so you don't have to manually start/manage your pipeline or pass it to the servlet.

Also check the [GATE embedded](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch7.html) documentation for other ideas on integrating GATE.